# Laravel 5.6 SMTP Connection could not be established with host smtp.mailtrap.io

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5, smtp

.env file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=myuser
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=TLS
```

I have done the following command to clear cache and config:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
```

I get the following error

> Connection could not be established with host smtp.mailtrap.io [php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.

I have also tried restaring local development server.

Comment: I don't think mailtrap uses TLS but that isn't the problem here.  Try to resolve smtp.mailtrap.io, it looks like a dns issue.

Comment: Are you paying for that? You do know MailHog, right? Free and does the same thing, and is insanely easy to use https://github.com/mailhog/MailHog

Comment: Set MAIL_ENCRYPTION=NULL and clear cache and config

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this: change the port and the encryption.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=[your username]
MAIL_PASSWORD=[your password]
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

And of course change username and password to your credentials.

Answer (score -1):

wrong code typo error

```
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=NULL
```

and do this

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems the server is not able to ping the destination address.

Try to clear cache, config cache, and restart apache2. It will work fine.

```
php artisan config:clear

php artisan cache:clear

sudo service apache2 restart
```

Note: clear browser cache & cookies as well.